# Part-of relationship School-student

Tags: design-patterns

So I am taking Design Pattern class, where a student gave "school-student" as a part-of relationship example. The professor argued that this relationship is not a part-of relationship, as students are not part of the definition of school. How true is that?

Answer (score 0):

Your professor, in my opinion, is correct. It's not that the student is incorrect, as a good case could be made for a student being `part-of` a school, rather it is because there is a more appropriate classification of the relationship to be had which is `has-a`. It is more natural and technically correct (when speaking about object relationships) to say a `school has students` than it is to say a `student is part of a school`.